# It's any way to decrease text in a table cell when it is too long?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm developing a calendar and I need to write events (text) in some days of the week(cell's of the table).
The problem is when the text in a cell is very large and the cell increases accordingly.

I need to have **fixed size cells and fixed size events** (div with text).
[image]
Code:

```css
table {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #6c757d !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.timetable_event {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
      <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="calendar-body">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1
        <div class="timetable_event">
          <small>Subject: [00000111] AUDICION Y LENGUAJE / LOGOPEDIA</small>
          <br>
          <small>From: 02:00</small>
          <br>
          <small>To: 05:33</small>
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
      <!--more code -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you want to make the text smaller, or do you want to cut it off?

Comment: I need to make text smaller(depending on how long it is) and have cell's with a fixed size. @connexo

Comment: You cannot fixate cell height, see my answer below. To decrease font-size depending upon content length, you will need to resort to Javascript.

Comment: Did you try setting `font-size` in `vw`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [line-clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) like so

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
overflow: hidden;
```

This allows you to limit the number of lines in the cell by changing `-webkit-line-clamp: 3;` and [works on all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp) except IE11.

Additionally, if you add the value to the `title` attribute of the cell, the entire text will show when you hover it.

```css
table {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #6c757d !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.timetable_event {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
      <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="calendar-body">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1
        <div class="timetable_event" title="Subject: [00000111] AUDICION Y LENGUAJE / LOGOPEDIA From: 02:00 To: 05:33">
          <small>Subject: [00000111] AUDICION Y LENGUAJE / LOGOPEDIA</small>
          <br>
          <small>From: 02:00</small>
          <br>
          <small>To: 05:33</small>
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
      <!--more code -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not valid, this example only hiddes text when the size is up to a number. I will use JS for it. Thanks for reply @volt

Comment: @adriano009 like I mentioned, you can control the maximum number of desired lines with `-webkit-line-clamp:` So, if you only want one line, change it to `-webkit-line-clamp: 1` if you want two lines, change it to `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to wrap the text in a `div` inside the `td`, and give that a fixed `height` along with `overflow-y: auto;` to make overflowing content accessible via scrolling:

```css
table {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #6c757d !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.timetable_event {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
  max-height: 2rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
      <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="calendar-body">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1
        <div class="timetable_event">
          <small>Subject: [00000111] AUDICION Y LENGUAJE / LOGOPEDIA</small>
          <br>
          <small>From: 02:00</small>
          <br>
          <small>To: 05:33</small>
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please note that you cannot fixate the height of a `td` - its height always is a result of the content in the highest `td` in that row.

To decrease font-size depending upon text length, you need Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const events = document.querySelectorAll('.timetable_event');
  
  for (event of events) {
    const factor = 1 / ((event.innerText.length || 1) / 35);
    if (factor < 1) event.style.fontSize = (factor * 0.875) + 'rem';
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #6c757d !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.timetable_event {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
  max-height: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
      <th>Sun</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="calendar-body">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>1
        <div class="timetable_event">
          <small>Subject: ABC</small>
          <br>
          <small>From: 02:00</small>
          <br>
          <small>To: 05:33</small>
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2
        <div class="timetable_event">
          <small>Subject: [00000111] AUDICION Y LENGUAJE / LOGOPEDIA</small>
          <br>
          <small>From: 02:00</small>
          <br>
          <small>To: 05:33</small>
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: With this example is created a scroll type text, but I don't need it. I need to decrease the size of the text (acording of how long it is) and get a fixed "timetable_event" div for inserting more than one. Any idea? @connexo

Comment: @adriano009 Added an example that adjusts font-size. The example assumes you want 100% of the original font-size for elements that have up to 35 characters.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the font-size using percentage value
e.g.

```
table {
  font-size: 100%; /*or 80% */
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: center !important;
  color: #6c757d !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

try to play around using percentage value for the font size that could help you...
i am not sure if you want to use javascript, because you can use javascript, to loop through the cells and get the text length on every cell and then set condition if length exceeds certain character use specific size percentage...

Comment: Yes this percentage value helps but not solves the problem. Thanks for your reply! @Kai